# GPLv3 + commercial license on the same project?

Tags: licensing, gpl

I'm trying to find a solution to publish my source as open source just for personal and no-profit use, and sell licenses for commercial use.

I see [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co) which uses GPLv3 for non commercial, and a custom license for commercial.

For what I know, everything under GPLv3 can be used everywhere without any limitation, so how can it works for Packery?

Can I do the same?

Comment: @KilianFoth I'm not askin this, I'm asking about dual license.

Comment: [answer in duplicate question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/242763/31260) covers this, explaining that copyright holder "...can license the code any which way you want, again and again and again. You could license it as GPL, and then have a client ask for a license for the MS-Pl for one of their projects, and then license it again under BSD..."

Comment: GPLv3 implications: https://criticalindirection.com/2016/07/13/the-gplv3-paranoia/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitly. It is called Multy-Licencing, and it is quite common:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing

The point is that you as a copy right holder can publish your work under as many separate licence as you like.

**UPDATE**

Typical use cases are these:

1. You are developing a library. You create a GPL version for opensource projects to use, and a comercial licenced version for the closed sourced projects. The GPL licence prohibits incorporation in closed source software, so these projects must choose the comercial licence. [Qt](http://qt.io) has a similar licencing scheme.
2. You are developing an end user software. You create a GPL version what everyone can use (you are not allowed to add any restrictions), and a comercial version with additional functionality. Those who need the additional functionality must choose the comercial licence.

Comment: Yes but if I read the GPLv3 License it says that with a piece of code licensed with it I can do whatever I want, so what prevent me to use the GPLv3 License for my commercial project instead of paying for the commercial license?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Mine is a CSS lib (Bootstrap Material Design), if I remember right, GPL allows to include libraries under GPL in closed source projects... Am I right?

Comment: No, thats LGPL what you mean.

Comment: @FezVrasta - using a GPL'd piece of code would require you to make your entire project available under the GPL (that's why it's considered "viral").

Comment: @ScottWhitlock The GPL only requires distributing the source code with the application. If you don't distribute the application, using it in-house, you don't have to distribute anything.

Comment: @bdsl - Yes, distribution was assumed, but I see if you're someone making an internal application and choosing between the licenses you could choose the GPL'd version and it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Any licensor can issue multiple (different) licenses aimed at different user segments, specifically with different "abilities to pay."

In your example, Packery used an "open ended" license for non-commercial use, and a more restrictive one for commercial use.

That kind of practice is quite common.